# Custom circular transition between two views

Tags: ios, quartz-core, cabasicanimation

I want to create an animation similar to the animation for changing inbetween different views in the Spy Mouse app. See this video for reference:

http://www.youtube.com/watch?v=ylFdl7W3Srw

[image: screenshot of the circular animation]

I am unable to do the same. My animation shows a rectangular region instead of a circular view.

```
CABasicAnimation *cornerRadiusAction = [CABasicAnimation animationWithKeyPath:@"cornerRadius"];    

cornerRadiusAction.timingFunction = [CAMediaTimingFunction functionWithName:kCAMediaTimingFunctionEaseInEaseOut];
cornerRadiusAction.duration = 5.0f;
cornerRadiusAction.toValue = [NSNumber numberWithFloat:self.view.bounds.size.height*2];
[self.view.layer addAnimation:cornerRadiusAction forKey:nil];
```

Answer (score 9, accepted):

#### Code in action.

[image]

#### Explanation.

You cannot achieve such an effect simply animating the `cornerRadius`. You need to use masking of the `CALayer` and animate change of the size of a circular mask. Code below does what you want. The animated `GIF`  shows it in action.

```
@property (weak, nonatomic) IBOutlet UIView *customView;

- (IBAction)buttonTapped:(id)sender
{
    // Set up the shape of the circle.
    CGFloat maskDiameter = sqrtf(powf(CGRectGetWidth(_customView.bounds), 2)
                                 + powf(CGRectGetHeight(_customView.bounds), 2));

    CAShapeLayer *mask = [CAShapeLayer layer];

    // Make a circular shape.
    mask.path = [UIBezierPath bezierPathWithRoundedRect:CGRectMake(0.0f,
                                                                   0.0f,
                                                                   maskDiameter,
                                                                   maskDiameter)
                                           cornerRadius:maskDiameter/2.0f].CGPath;
    // Center the shape in the view.
    mask.position = CGPointMake((CGRectGetWidth(_customView.bounds) - maskDiameter)/2,
                                (CGRectGetHeight(_customView.bounds) - maskDiameter)/2);

    // Fill the circle.
    mask.fillColor = [UIColor blackColor].CGColor;

    // Add as a mask to the parent layer
    _customView.layer.mask = mask;

    // Animate.
    CABasicAnimation *animation = [CABasicAnimation animationWithKeyPath:@"path"];
    animation.duration = 5.0f;
    animation.fillMode = kCAFillModeForwards;
    animation.removedOnCompletion = NO;

    // Create new path.
    CGPathRef newPath = [UIBezierPath bezierPathWithRoundedRect:CGRectMake(maskDiameter/2.0f,
                                                                           maskDiameter/2.0f,
                                                                           0.0f,
                                                                           0.0f)
                                                   cornerRadius:0.0f].CGPath;
    // Set start and end values.
    animation.fromValue = (id)mask.path;
    animation.toValue = (__bridge id)newPath;

    // Start the animaiton.
    [mask addAnimation:animation forKey:@"path"];

}
```

Comment: Heii I wana to use the same effect in changing between two views for that i provided mask contents from next view,
mask.contents = (id)[[self getImageFromNextView] CGImage];
but it just shows similar to your gif, first it removes the view using black similar to yours then it add next view but i want that it just hides the above view so that back view can be easily seen.

Comment: I would place the second view (the one you want to reveal) underneath the view you want to hide. In my case, the black area you see in the gif is just an empty view. Don't add stuff to the mask contents. Use it only to animate the disappearing of the view.

Answer (score 5):

This is [@RaffAI's answer](https://stackoverflow.com/a/25060460/3151675) in **Swift** as a function you can call with any view you want:

```
func circleAnim(_ view: UIView, duration: CFTimeInterval) {
    let maskDiameter = CGFloat(sqrtf(powf(Float(view.bounds.width), 2) + powf(Float(view.bounds.height), 2)))
    let mask = CAShapeLayer()
    let animationId = "path"

    // Make a circular shape.
    mask.path = UIBezierPath(roundedRect: CGRect(x: 0, y: 0, width: maskDiameter, height: maskDiameter), cornerRadius: maskDiameter / 2).cgPath

    // Center the shape in the view.
    mask.position = CGPoint(x: (view.bounds.width - maskDiameter) / 2, y: (view.bounds.height - maskDiameter) / 2)

    // Fill the circle.
    mask.fillColor = UIColor.black.cgColor

    // Add as a mask to the parent layer.
    view.layer.mask = mask

    // Animate.
    let animation = CABasicAnimation(keyPath: animationId)
    animation.duration = duration
    animation.fillMode = .forwards
    animation.isRemovedOnCompletion = false

    // Create a new path.
    let newPath = UIBezierPath(roundedRect: CGRect(x: maskDiameter / 2, y: maskDiameter / 2, width: 0, height: 0), cornerRadius: 0).cgPath

    // Set start and end values.
    animation.fromValue = mask.path
    animation.toValue = newPath

    // Start the animation.
    mask.add(animation, forKey: animationId)
}
```